# REOPENED: How is my question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

My question, [What can I expect working with a recruiter who sends template messages without even including names?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/112834), was put on hold as "off-topic".

I believe that it was off-topic the way I originally wrote it (as a "should I work with this recruiter" question). But 2/3 of the close votes came *after* I made my edit.

I think that the question "what can I expect from this type of recruiter" is objectively answerable, but maybe I'm too inexperienced to realize it.

Why is my question off-topic?

PS - nobody who cast a close vote was very helpful as indicating *how* it is off-topic and how I can improve it, so I can't do so without coming to meta to discuss it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what it's worth, I don't agree with the exact close reason with the question as it currently stands:

> Questions asking for advice on a specific choice, such as what job to take or what skills to learn, are difficult to answer objectively and are rarely useful for anyone else. Instead of asking which decision to make, try asking how to make the decision, or for more specific details about one element of the decision.

I see it that you're asking how to respond to these pre-canned emails and you're not asking "whether" to respond to them, or whether or not to apply for those jobs.

Your previous edit would fall under that closure umbrella, but the last edit was made approximately 2 hours before the close happened.

What I think happened here is that your question collected a few close votes before the edit (valid at that point), and the last close vote after the edit by someone who didn't really bother to read the question after the edit.

We sometimes see people in the review queues stabbing the "close" button simply because 3 or 4 people have also pressed the "close" button (this is "confirmation bias")

You got unlucky there.  I'm voting to reopen this question.

Comment: Thanks. It's entirely possible that people just smashed the close button in the review queue for sure. I definitely recall one close vote *before* the edit, but I guess that was the nail in the coffin for some people. I think reviewers on Stack Exchange tend to be a bit trigger happy at times...

Comment: Now reopened...